# unable to assign text box value to another text box in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to display one text box value in another text box while clicking button. im able to show value on div but not in text box

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){


 var val= $("#txtValue").val();
$("#txtValue1").text(val);
$("#myDiv").text(val);
})
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtValue">

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input type = "button" id = "btnSubmit" value="Submit">
<input type="text" id="txtValue1" text="">
```

Comment: Where is your textValue textbox. I can see none in your code?

Comment: Just to be clear, these are called `input`s not to be confused with `textarea`s which are handled differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `input type='text'` you need:

```
 $("#txtValue1").val(val);
```

It is an input; inputs take values

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhhqb6sf/)

Comment: Great - if you are happy with it, you can accept it as an answer.